# What are the important shastrath debates in ancient india?

Tags: scripture, history, dharma, adi-shankaracharya, darshan

I have heard of only one debate which was between Adi Shankaracharya and Mandana Mishra. Can you list some important debates other than the aforementioned one? Are there any scriptures/books which contain such debates?

Comment: One such debate was hosted by Bhaskararaya at Lalitaghat. Debate of Adishankar in Nepal(where Neela Saraswati asked him to leave Nepal instanstly), debate of Bandi & Ashtavakra, Debate of Keshava Kashmiri & Chaitanya Mahaprabhu, debate of Sarvanada & Kabir, debate of Ramanujacharya & Jain Charvakas, there are endless debates in Tamil, & many such more to go.

Comment: There is Shata-Dushani by Swami Desikan - where he refutes 100 opposing points.

Answer (score 1):

There is an entire chapter about the debate between Vidushi Gargi and Rishi Yajnavalkya in [Brihadaranyaka Upanishad.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc118359.html)

Another famous shastrarth is [between](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29584/19001) Kumaril Bhatt and other Buddhist scholars.